# missing 1 required positional argument (emp1)

Tags: python

I have written code to count employees using class but the the code doesn't work.

```
class employee:
    empCount = 0;
    
    def employee(self, name, salary):
        self.name = name;
        self.salary = salary;
        employee.empCount += 1;
 
    def displayCount(self):
        print ("\nTotal Employee %d", Employee.empCount);

    def displyEmployee(self):
        print('Name:',self.name,'Salary:',self.salary);
    
emp1 = employee('ABS', 2000)
```

Comment: Please repost your code with proper indentation. Paste the code then use the `{}` to mark it as a pre-formatted code block.

Comment: And post the full traceback.

Comment: On the line `def displayCount(self): print ("\nTotal Employee %d", Employee.empCount);` it is `Employee` but the class name is `employee` (t.i. lowercased).

Comment: ```emp1 = employee('ABS', 2000)``` but there is no ```__init__()``` in your class.

Comment: `def employee` should be `def __init__`

Comment: The posted code does not get the error in your title (it gets the *opposite* error, complaining `employee` takes no arguments). @Barmar's comment is correct for the code posted, but the code you posted is *not* the code you claim raises that error.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has a number of problems that are preventing it from working as you expect:

- You did not declare your constructor properly. When you do `employee('ABS', 200)`, Python looks for a function called `__init__` on the class object. You declared your constructor as `employee`, similarly to how you would do so in C-based languages. This won't work.
- You store the employee count as a variable scoped to the class object. You can do this but I wouldn't because it's a misuse of that capability. Instead, you should create a list of employees and get the length of the list.
- Instead of declaring `display` functions, you should overload the `__str__` function, which returns a string representing the object.
- Class names should be PascalCase (this doesn't keep your code from working but you should definitely address it).

```
class Employee:

    def __init__(self, name, salary):
        self.name = name
        self.salary = salary

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Name: {self.name}, Salary: {self.salary}"

employees = []
employees.append(Employee('ABS', 200))
len(employees) # 1
```